# Is there a way to prevent selection across elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two `div`s. Users can select text in either `div`. When they drag from one to the other, it selects parts of both and creates a big, ugly, unpredictable selection.

Is there any way to force a selection to finish in the same element it started in (i.e. by preventing it from extending into other components regardless of where the user moves their cursor)?

Comment: It seems that the CSS [`user-select:element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) is intended for this purpose, but support is limited. `Supported only in Internet Explorer. Enables selection to start within the element; however, the selection will be contained by the bounds of that element.`

Comment: This does not seem like a common issue . It might be help to post your code